# Having issues drawing 3D cube's edges with OpenGL 3

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, indices, vertices

I'm trying to draw 3D cube's vertices (edges only) using OpenGL (4.3 core profile), I know the `glPolygonMode` function but I'd like not to draw the intermediate diagonal lines. I declare my vertices and my indices like so :

```cpp
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec3 color;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 uv;
};

Vertex vertices[8];

// Front vertices
vertices[0].pos = glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);
vertices[1].pos = glm::vec3(+0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);
vertices[2].pos = glm::vec3(+0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);
vertices[3].pos = glm::vec3(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);

// Back vertices
vertices[4].pos = glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
vertices[5].pos = glm::vec3(+0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
vertices[6].pos = glm::vec3(+0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);
vertices[7].pos = glm::vec3(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);

GLuint indices[36] = {
    0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, // Front
    1, 5, 6, 6, 2, 1, // Right
    7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7, // Back
    4, 0, 3, 3, 7, 4, // Left
    4, 5, 1, 1, 0, 4, // Bottom
    3, 2, 6, 6, 7, 3 // Top
};
```

My buffer is updated accordingly :

```cpp
// Bind Vertex Array
glBindVertexArray(_VAO);

// Bind VBO to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER type so that all calls to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER use VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _VBO);

// Upload vertices to VBO
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesNb * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Bind EBO to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER type so that all calls to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER use EBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _EBO);

// Updload indices to EBO
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesNb * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I'm using `glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);` to draw my cube's edges, but for some reason it doesn't draw some edges and I don't understand why.

If I use GL_TRIANGLES, it works pretty well though when I want to render my 3D cube in fill-mode. Does anyone know what I'm missing here ? Is it an issue with the indices ?

(The "cube" below has a custom size of `(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f)`)

[image: OpenGL cube]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indices form [`GL_TRIANGLES`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) primitives rather than  [`GL_LINES`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) primitives. See `GL_LINES`:

> Vertices 0 and 1 are considered a line. Vertices 2 and 3 are considered a line. And so on.

The indices form the primitives. Change the indices:

```cpp
GLuint indices[] = {
    0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, // Front
    4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, // Back
    0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7
};
```

```cpp
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Or use `GL_LINE_STRIP`.

Comment: @wcochran Then you'd have to use a very tricky index order or [Primitive Restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart).

Comment: good point... if you are going to shade the cube then you are going to want to represent each vertex 3 times (once for each adjacent face) since there will be 3 different normals. So probably want to  redo things anyway...

Comment: @wcochran If you want to draw lines you don't need normal vectors at all. If you want to render polygons (triangles) you will need a different set of indexes anyway (`GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, ...)

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. @Rabbid76 So I assume that it is not possible to have the same vertices and indices for both GL_TRIANGLES and GL_LINES ? I mean, if I want to have 2 rendering modes for my cube (filled and edges only), I would have two different buffers with different vertices and indices (at least indices) ?

Comment: @MajorSquirrel Of course it is possible to have the same vertices. However the indices form the primitive. Different primitives required different indices. You don't need 2 different vertex buffers, but you need 2 different index buffers. You can create 2 VAOs which use the same vertex specification and the same vertex buffers, but use different index buffers (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`).

Comment: @Rabbid76 The "indices form the primitive" sentence makes things clearer to me as I can have specific vertices but, in the end, indices define the primitive to be drawn, thanks a lot.